# How to learn piano with MIDI files and a keyboard?

Tags: piano, learning, keyboard, midi

I am new to piano, and was hoping to learn with the help of MIDI files. I have a keyboard, a Casio LK-44, and have successfully connected it to my computer with a USB MIDI connector. This can play MIDI files from my computer, and the keys light to show keystrokes.

This keyboard has a function that teaches you a song by only continuing the song upon the correct keystroke, and it lights the keys to show which one to press. This allows the person to learn the song at their own pace, and speed up to the proper tempo as they learn. Is there a program that can do this with MIDI files? When I run them through the keyboard, they just play automatically. Thank you.

Comment: You did not mention the sort of pieces you are interested to learn. Learning piano is something completely different from touching the correct keys in some selected pieces - it is really hard without ability to read a score. The number of keys is 61, which is also on (or even below) the low end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no MIDI specification for such lighting and fingering information.

Casio has an [SMF Converter](http://music.casio.com/e/smf/) tool:

> SMF Converter is software that converts commercially available Standard MIDI file (SMF) data to a format that is supported by CASIO electronic musical instruments, and then transfers the converted data to the instrument. After data is transferred, it can be used with the lesson function for lesson play.

However, the LK-44 is not in the list of supported models, so it might or might not work.

Comment: Thank you for this information. This seems to be the program I was looking for, but unfortunately my keyboard is incompatible. I will keep my eyes out for a supported model, and will work with MIDI files in the meantime. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use this software http://pianobooster.sourceforge.net/
to play the midi file. Click on option follow me, the music will wait for you to press the correct keys and continue.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin also may come in handy to visualize MIDI in your computer: http://www.4drx.com/plugins/virtualkeyboard

(You can run inside many standard DAWS such as Cubase, Ableton and Logic)